# Decrypting an AES256-rijdeal encrypted file with initialization vector

Tags: android, encryption, rijndael

I've got a tricky situation at the moment.

I need to create an android method that will decrypt an encrypted file that has been encrypted like this:

- AES256 (Rijndael)
- Cipher-Block-Chaining (CBC) using an initialization vector of 16 bytes that look like:

{ 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 122, 100 }

I also know the encryption key to the file, but for now let's say it's: "Boat"

I've been searching around on Google but I could not find a online that used this combination of encryption. Some involved the Rijndael algorithm but didn't let me choose an initialization vector, while others did not support AES256 at all.

Can someone point me into the right direction where to find an example or post some sample code that does the above?

N.B. I don't know if it's important to mention but the output file is always .pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very standard configuration, hard to believe you didn't find any samples. All you need to do is create an `IvParameterSpec` from your IV bytes and initialize the `Cipher` with it. Something like this:

```
SecretKey key = getEncryptionKey(); 
byte[] iv = new byte[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, (byte)144, (byte)233, 122, 100 };
byte[] cipherBytes = readEncryptedFile();
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
IvParameterSpec ivParams = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, ivParams);
byte[] plaintext = cipher.doFinal(cipherBytes);
```

BTW, 'Rijndael' is the same as AES, so you'd get better results if you just search for 'AES'.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I fill `key` with my own key?

Comment: OK, getting there. What sort string format? Hexadecimal? Base64 encoded? Not actually a key, but a password? Replace characters and post a sample if you are not sure.

Comment: It looks like this: `$0rEoS5uAkNk5ovovVWPXsW2buwUy0TU` As far as I know this is not encoded at all. This IS the encryption key.

Comment: If it is a string, it mean is is encoded. A key is a sequence of bytes. You have to check with whoever produced this key about the actual format. If you assume that each character is a byte (unlikely, unless you have a really weak key), you can convert to a `SecretKey` like this: `SecretKey = new SecretKeySpec("$0rEoS5uAkNk5ovovVWPXsW2buwUy0TU".getBytes("ASCII"));`

Comment: Ahh I get it now, I didn't realize I had to create the `SecretKey` using `SecretKeySpec`. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Buggers the mind. First choose AES-256 encryption, and then more than half the key size by allowing ASCII characters only. Keys should be specified in bytes, and *if* they are needed as String, hex or base64 encode them.

Comment: @owlstead Sad but true. If it were only this one case... Some people even pad the string with zeros if it's shorter than the 128/256 bits needed.